# How to pass parameters to dependent class in C# (.Net 6.0) using DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API project in C#. I'm relatively new to this and dependency injection. So far I've used DI without much problem but I'm struggling to figure out how to pass an argument to a dependent class that is injected.

I have a set of services (`ServiceA` and `ServiceB`), which are inherited from a base class which is also a `BackgroundService`.

The parent class (`BaseService`) has a the `DataProcessor` class as a dependency. This processor class requires a constructor argument which indicates the ID of the service (which is available as a property on the corresponding service class).

My classes:

```
public abstract class BaseService : BackgroundService
{
    public abstract string ID { get; }
    protected DataProcessor dp;

    protected BaseService(DataProcessor _dp)
    {
        dp = _dp;
    }
}

public class ServiceA : BaseService
{
    public override string ID => "SA";

    public ServiceA(DataProcessor _dp): base(_dp)
    {
    }
}

public class ServiceB : BaseService
{
    public override string ID => "SB";

    public ServiceA(DataProcessor _dp): base(_dp)
    {
    }
}

public class DataProcessor
{
    private string serviceID;

    public DataProcessor(string _serviceID)
    {
        serviceID = _serviceID;
    }
}
```

This is how I configure this on the startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<DataProcessor>();

    // Add Service A
    services.AddSingleton<ServiceA>();
    services.AddHostedService<ServiceA>(p =>
    {
        return (ServiceA)p.GetServices<BaseService>().Where(a => a.GetType() == typeof(ServiceA)).First();
    });

    // Add Service B
    services.AddSingleton<ServiceB>();
    services.AddHostedService<ServiceB>(p =>
    {
        return (ServiceB)p.GetServices<BaseService>().Where(a => a.GetType() == typeof(ServiceB)).First();
    });
}
```

The question is: how do I pass the `ID` property of the `Service` class to the `DataProcessor` class?

**Note:** I've simplified the code and setup for the purpose of the question.

I have tried by creating an `Initialize(string ID)` method on the `DataProcessor` class and calling that within the constructor of my `BaseService` class. This works but I don't like it as a solution, as I have to manually call this Initialize method.

I've searched a lot and read several similar questions/posts, but really couldn't figure it out.

It does seem like a relatively common request, so might be that I'm not using the DI correctly here or that I have the wrong expectation.

Thank you!

Comment: Dependencies are a directed graph. A dependency should have no knowledge of how it is used. If a data processor needs to know which service it is processing. Then you have defined your dependencies backwards.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyLakeman, that makes sense. I think I can rework the **DataProcessor** class to adhere to that. However, I think the question still stands, is it possible to pass arguments to a dependent class? Or, in theory, this should never be the case if we want the dependency to have no knowledge of how they are used?

Comment: The DI container assumes that one `Type`, has one service instance. With the exception of `IEnumerable<>`, which will populate a collection of all registered instances. Though you can use generics to include a type parameter in the service. For example `IOptions<T>` / `ILogger<T>` you may be familiar with.

Comment: You could use a delegate with the appropriate return type and then register an instance of it that returns your data.